# Find line in one csv in another csv

Tags: python, string, csv, match

I have been using this code below to find exact matches of strings from one csv to another:

```
with open(filename1, 'rb') as file1:
file1reader = csv.reader(file1)

for line1 in file1reader:
    with open(filename2, 'rb') as file2:
        file2reader = csv.reader(file2)

        for linenum, line2 in enumerate(file2reader, start=1):
            if str(line1) == str(line2):
                print('match found')
                matches.append(str(linenum))
                counts.append(linenum) 
                if len(matches) >= MAX_COUNT:
                    break

    if len(matches) >= MAX_COUNT:
        break
```

Now, I have a file that has strings that are partial matches to another file. I would also like to have these be a match as exact strings are in the above code. I tried replacing the `==` with `in` but had no luck. Any help?

Example:

```
string1 = humpty

string2 = humptydumpty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking both directions:

```
if (str(line1) in str(line2)) or (str(line2) in str(line1)):
```

I don't think the parentheses are strictly necessary but they make the meaning clearer.

Comment: Tried this but still no luck. The script seems to not be able to find a match, even though I am sure there are substrings that are present in the first list that are present in string in the second list.

Comment: I think it is doing this because it is comparing list objects and thus string1 = ['humpty'] and string2 = ['humptydumpty']

Comment: If that's the case, then `if str(string1[0]) in str(string2[0])` would work.. assuming they are one-item lists

Comment: Yup, that's it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to `check if a substring is present in a string`.

For this you can use the [in](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) operator:

Example:

```
if "humpty" in "humptydumpty": 
    print "Ok"
```

In your case:

```
if string1 in string2: 
    print "Ok"
```